# Can't Purchase music on a WP8 Nokia Lumia 520 with My Family Settings on but unrestricted

Tags: 8.0, music, parental-control

My son has a Nokia Lumia 520 and wants to be able to purchase music through the Xbox music store. We navigate to the track click Buy and we get the message:

> Can't Download
>
> The My Family Settings for your account prevent you from downloading this item. Your parent can manage My Family Settings at WindowsPhone.com

Looking at those settings, we have free/paid downloads turned on, and age restrictions unlimited. These look to be app only settings?

Am I missing something? UK user if that helps.

Comment: If your son's family settings age restrictions are unlimited then why did you set a family protection on his phone from the beginning ? Try to disable it then try to download again.

Comment: We initially setup the family protection to filter out more grown up games, but had to take it off due to it not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I needed to login Xbox.com as well and manage the settings under Security Family and forums>>Privacy and Online safety. (For both Xbox One and Xbox 360).

Once this was done he could download songs. (This will probably fix the gaming filters that we originally wanted to setup too.