# how to set up an family setting?

Tags: games, kids-corner, parental-control

How to set up a family setting on a windows phone? Because I have tried many times when I was downloading some applications and  I stuck by that massage of family setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3209/106

Answer (score 0):

You may use Kids corner. This is a secondary home page for Lumia phones. You can add apps/games etc as per your choice. For more details go here to see [how to setup kids corner for Lumia 520 guide?](http://www.nokia.com/mea-en/support/product/lumia520/userguidance/?action=singleTopic&topic=GUID-140D4BDE-B69E-49D8-B130-601A8064BEF0)